# Unable to maintain two parallel sessions while running tests using testNG(Selenium) using Spring?

Tags: java, spring, selenium, testng, spring-ioc

I am facing problem while running simple tests using TestNG with Selenium using Spring framework, the issue is that it unable to start two parallel session (without parallel its working fine without any issue). 
The overall objective is to launch two parallel browsers and each session managed by springIOC. Without Spring its easy to do using static threadLocal, but with spring i want to maintain two separate IOC containers managed by spring itself.

Please help me to resolve this issue. Code is available on below link,
https://github.com/priyankshah217/AutomationFrameworkUsingSpringDI.git

testNg.xml

```
<test name="search-engine-test">
    <classes>
        <class name="com.test.framework.tests.TestAmazonWeb"/>
    </classes>
</test>
```

TestConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.test.framework")
public class TestConfig {

  WebDriver webDriver;

  @Bean
  public WebDriver getDriver() {
    if (webDriver == null || ((ChromeDriver) webDriver).getSessionId() == null) {
      webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
    }
    return webDriver;
  }
}
```

BaseTest.java

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestConfig.class})
public class BaseTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {

    @Autowired
    private WebDriver webDriver;

    @AfterMethod
    public void tearDown() {
        webDriver.quit();
    }
}
```

GoogleHomePage.java

```
@PageObject
public class GoogleHomePage extends BasePage {
    @FindBy(name = "q")
    private WebElement searchTextbox;

    public void enterGoogleSearch() {
        hardWait();
        searchTextbox.sendKeys("Selenium");
        searchTextbox.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
    }

}
```

All Page objects are spring component with WebDriver (autowired).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a few issues in your codebase which is preventing concurrency support.

1. The `autowired` `WebDriver` instance should have been defined with scope as `prototype` instead of `singleton` (which is the default scope). That way each of the page objects would basically get their own WebDriver instance. This is in a way a bit of a convoluted approach though when your `@Test` method spans across multiple pages.
2. The way in which you have handled post processing (wherein you are initialising the page factory) also has to be changed if you are going to be working with a prototype scoped webdriver, because you now cannot afford to autowire the webdriver in there, but it now has to be extracted from the page object class.

To explain the changes in a much more easy to understand way, I have raised a pull request against your repository.

Refer to https://github.com/priyankshah217/AutomationFrameworkUsingSpringDI/pull/2

for the full set of changes.

Comment: Thanks for explaining.. it worked like charm.. Just one question, in your code  i can see you override "run" and there you explicitly quit driver. Is there any way to handle closing driver in fixture methods afterMethod?, because when i tried it did not work and closing only one instance of browser.

Comment: @PriyankShah - The reason why my PR takes care of quitting the driver in the `IHookable#run` implementation is because, once the `@Test` method gets executed, there are issues in terms of getting hold of the `WebDriver` instance from the `afterTestExecution` because, spring by its behaviour if it doesn't find a bean, it creates it and I am not very spring savvy to figure out how to get it stop that. That is why I had to handle WebDriver cleanup in the way its done.